# Transfer folders based on first letter and highest level

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy only directories that begin with the letter "u" up to a server from a workstation that is used to collect data.  I cannot save the data directly to the server from the workstation due to security reasons. The script I have so far does copy the folders I want with one major problem, it creates unique copies of sub-directories that begin with the letter "u" that are found within the folders that begin with the letter "u" thus creating recursive duplicates of any folder that begins with "u" from the entire tree I am pointing at.

I am hoping that there is a way in PowerShell to create a script that will:

1. search a directory for folders that start with "u"
2. copy each and only the highest level folders in the directory that start with "u" recursively.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$from = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test\[uU]* -Recurse |
        where PSIsContainer
$to = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\New folder"  
Copy-Item $from $to -Recurse
```

Is this even possible?

It is worth noting that I will eventually want this script to not overwrite or skip folders with matching names but be additive to existing folders with matching names.  I just haven't got to that yet.

Comment: What version of Powershell are you on?

Comment: `$from` should already have the list of folders whose name begins with "u". You don't need `[uU]*` BTW, since PowerShell is case-insensitive by default. `u*` is sufficient. To get just the topmost folders you could iterate over the (sorted) array and remove all elements whose `FullName` begins with the `FullName` of the previous element.